# How do I get the kernel for this phone?

Tags: kernel, open-source

I think companies are legally required to publish the kernel for their phone somewhere.

I bought a phone derived from this one: https://www.paxtechnology.com/android-smart-pos and can't find the kernel for it. On "legal information" on android settings, I enter a very large HTML file that I cannot navigate properly and I don't know what it does.

It's the Pax M30 by the way

Comment: send request on homepage they will reply within 24 hours ;)

Comment: Do ask, as it may be on a Chinese server somewhere. I'm reminded of [Naomi (SexyCyborg) Wu's attempt to get GPL code in-person](https://twitter.com/RealSexyCyborg/status/1428706989274583049) and based on her [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/Vj04MKykmnQ?t=550) it seems some level of compliance was reached with her particular phone manufacturer as least when she recorded the video.